# Complex function of class $C^m$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers

Let $m$ a positive integer and consider the function
$$f(z)=\vert z\vert^\alpha z$$ with $\alpha>0$. I have to find the value of $\alpha$ for which $f\in C^m(\mathbb{C},\mathbb{C})$.
Now if $\alpha$ is an even integer, $f$ becomes a polynomial, so $f\in C^\infty (\mathbb{C},\mathbb{C})$. What about the other cases?

Comment: In your notation, does $f\in C^1(\mathbb{C},\mathbb{C})$ mean that

$\forall z\in\mathbb{C}\exists\lim_{|h|\rightarrow0}\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}\in\mathbb{C}$ and that such limit is a continuous function of $z$?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli People don't usually write $C^m$ when they mean complex differentiability.

Comment: Thanks @pizza, I was not familiar with the notation.

Comment: For complex $z$, the function $|z|^\alpha$ is not a polynomial in $z$ for $\alpha\not = 0$.

Comment: @anomaly I mean a polynomial in $z$ and $\overline{z}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is $C^\infty$ smooth outside of the origin. It is also homogeneous of degree $\alpha+1$; that is $f(tz) = t^{\alpha +1}f(z)$ for $t\ge 0$.

First order partial derivatives are homogeneous of degree $\alpha$; this can be seen from the definition of derivative. Therefore, $m$th order derivatives are homogeneous of degree $\alpha+1-m$. We have three cases:

- $\alpha+1-m<0$. The $m$th partial derivatives are unbounded near the origin, hence $f\notin C^m$.
- $\alpha+1-m>0$. The $m$th partial derivatives have limit $0$ at the origin. It follows that the function itself has zero derivative there (this takes a proof; use Mean Value theorem). Hence  $f\in C^m$.
- $\alpha+1-m=0$. The $m$th partial derivatives are $0$-degree homogeneous. They are either constant (in which case $f$ is a polynomial, so $\alpha$ is even) or not constant (in which case they do not have limit $0$ at the origin, hence  $f\notin C^m$.)